# Install STworkbench on Linux

Tags: linux, rational-test-workbench

I am trying to install STworkbench on ubuntu 12.04 but i get an error as below:

```
************************************************************************
* Looks like you are trying to install on a Ubuntu system              *
*                                                                      *
* This is not officially supported, but can be made to work            *
*                                                                      *
* Look at the following links and carry out the steps listed there     *
* and then rerun this script with the --debian flag                    *
*                                                                      *
              http://stlinux.com/install/ubuntu                        *
*                                                                      *
************************************************************************
```

I followed the installation guide from http://www.stlinux.com/devel/stw.

What can i do to fix this?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions from the message?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add "-d" in your install command:

$ ./install -d stworkbench

Comment: Could you provide more detail into why this would answer the question and the outcome of using that flag? To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).